# Difference between iOS SDK and simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm targeting iOS 5.1 with my app. I am running against the **iPhone 5.1 Simulator**, but I have noticed my project is listed as **1 target, iOS SDK 6.0**.

The deployment target is listed as 5.1.

What is the difference between the SDK and simulator target? Should I be using a 5.1 SDK and if so how would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDK represents the API that you can use. The deployment target is the lowest version number that you're certifying that it will run on.

If the SDK and deployment target differ then you need to be careful that you don't use any APIs that are not available on older versions (or you disable that functionality if it's not there).

Comment: Will xcode warn me if I use an API not available on the 5.1 target?

Comment: Typically no. That's why I put the emphasis on you certifying that it works. Seems like that kind of thing that _could_ be automated. But unfortunately they don't. Also, be aware that the simulator historically hasn't 100% matched the API. Be sure to test on a device.

Comment: Bit of a headache! Well I tried to switch down to 5.1 for the SDK but it doesn't appear to be installed anymore. Any idea how I would re-install it?

Comment: There's no official way of doing it as far as I'm aware. The simplest way would be to use an old version of Xcode (if you can find a copy).

Comment: OK thanks. I'll just have to be careful not to use anything new in iOS6. Thanks for your answers.